# Why C++ array class is taking more time to operate on, than the C-style array?

Tags: c++, arrays, time, compiler-optimization

I have written a simple code to compare the time taken to operate on the elements of two arrays (both of same size), one defined by C++ array class and the other by plain C-style array. The code I have used is

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>
    #include <chrono>   

    using namespace std;

    const int size = 1E8;
    const int limit = 1E2;

    array<float, size> A;
    float B[size];

    int main () {

       using namespace std::chrono;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
       auto start = steady_clock::now();
           
       for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                A.at(j) *= 1.;     

       auto end = steady_clock::now();
       auto span = duration_cast<seconds> (end - start).count();
       
       cout << "Time taken for array A is: " << span << " sec" << endl;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
       start = steady_clock::now();
       
       for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
               B[j] *= 1.;
    
       end = steady_clock::now();
       span = duration_cast<seconds> (end - start).count();
       
       cout << "Time taken for array B is: " << span << " sec" << endl;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

       return 0;
    }
```

which I have compiled and run with

```
g++ array.cxx
./a.out
```

The output I get is the following

```
Time taken for array A is: 52 sec
Time taken for array B is: 22 sec
```

Why does the C++ array class takes much longer to operate on?

Comment: Enable compiler optimizations, then get the timings.

Comment: I wouldn't put `1E8` floats on the stack anyway.

Comment: Because array bounds checking takes time. You **know** that `j` is in bounds, because you wrote it that way. You don’t need to check it again with`A.at(j)`. `A[j]` does the same thing without that waste of time.

Comment: measuring runtime isnt that easy. Multiplying numbers by 1 can be achieved by not doing anything and a decent compiler should realize that. You measured something but not the difference between a c-array and a c++ array

Comment: Do not use `using namespace std;` just like that.  The reason is that there is a `std::size`, and it clashes with your `size` variable name.

Answer (score 7):

The [`std::array::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) member function does bounds-checking so, of course, there is some extra overhead. If you want a fairer comparison use [`std::array::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at), just like the plain array.

Comment: I also tried with the `operator[]` for array `A`, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @XCSM Did you enable optimizations? They can make a huge difference especially with templated code. Compile with `g++ -O2 array.cxx` to enable compiler optimization level 2.

Comment: I must say that optimization made significant changes. The previous operation is too simple, so I changed it to `A[j] += 1. + 2*A[j]` and `B[j] += 1. + 2*B[j]`. The timings after enabling `-O2` flag are `13372 ms` for `A` and `13334 ms` for `B`, using `high_resolution_clock`. With `-O3` flag, it is `8793 ms` for `A` and `8755 ms` for `B`. So then, should I always use optimization with C++ array class?

Comment: @XCSM I suggest you always enable optimizations for every program unless you have a specific reason not to (for example, ease of debugging).